# Trying to add field to checkout with LayoutProcessor Plugin

Tags: magento2, checkout

I have been using a couple of guides to add a field to the shipping step in checkout:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_custom_checkbox.html

I was able to successfully add my field by overriding the LayoutProcessor for a different extension, but when I try to just override Magento's LayoutProcessor, the field doesn't appear. So I think think it has something to do with how I'm creating the plugin, and not so much a problem with my code.

Below is the code I am trying to use to create the checkout field:

> Namespace\Module\etc\frontend\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
    <plugin name="custom-checkout" type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\CheckoutLayoutPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>

</config>
```

> Namespace\Module\Plugin\CheckoutLayoutPlugin.php

```
<?php
namespace Module\Namespace\Plugin;
class CheckoutLayoutPlugin
{
    public function afterProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $processor, $jsLayout){

    $test2 = 'tli_test2';

    $newField = [
        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
        'config' => [
            'customScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes',
            'customEntry' => null,
            'template' => 'ui/form/field',
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
            'tooltip' => [
                'description' => 'description'
            ]
        ],
        'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.custom_attributes.' . $test2,
        'label' => 'Custom Label',
        'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
        'sortOrder' => 0,
        'validation' => [
            'required-entry' => true
        ],
        'options' => [],
        'filterBy' => null,
        'customEntry' => null,
        'visible' => true
    ];

    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$test2] = $newField;

    return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

This alone should be enough to at least render the field, even if it doesn't do anything, but it still does not appear on the shipping step of checkout.

Comment: How to add css to the new field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, we've all had one of these days... Turns out it was a typo:

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
               ^---| Should be "Magento"
```